# Execute program at certain time

Tags: python

I want to create an alarm program in python so I can wake up yo a music video instead of an annoying alarm clock. I have looked at the time module but time.time() and time.ctime() don't work. I tried to use time.clock() but it always allows the if statement to execute, any suggestions as to how I can make the program execute the video launcher logic at a certain time?

my program:

```
import os, time

while 0 == 0:
    if time.clock() == 0.018796:
        os.system("firefox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09wdQP1FFR0")
        time.sleep(120) #to avoid opening many windows
```

Comment: What you want is the `datetime` module - that specifies time of day and day of week, so you can have more useful tests. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Why not use [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?  Or, if you run Windows, [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: have you tried https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html?

Comment: thanks @iCodez it looks like it should work perfectly